# BigQuery Count Appears to be Processing Data

Tags: google-bigquery

I noticed that running a `SELECT count(*) FROM myTable` on my larger BQ tables yields long running times, upwards of 30/40 seconds despite the validator claiming the query processes 0 bytes. This doesn't seem quite right when 500 GB queries run faster. Additionally, total row counts are listed under details -> Table Info. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get total row counts instantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a count BigQuery still needs to allocate resources (such as: slot units, shards etc). You might be reaching some limits which cause a delay. For example, the slots default per project is 2,000 units.

BigQuery execution plan provides very detail information about the process which can help you better understand the source of the delay. 
One way to overcome this is to use an approximate method described in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate_aggregate_functions#approx_count_distinct)

This Slide by Google might also help you

[image]

For more details [see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1766&v=UueWySREWvk) about how to understand the execution plan

Comment: What do you mean by "BQ will allocate a shade for each process unit"? I never knew about the execution plan. I just had a look at it and a count query resulted in two stages, an input and an output. I still don't understand why the query is free if it creates process units and performs operations.

Comment: I update my answer with more details and a link which you can use to learn more about the execution plan. This should help you understand what's happening under the hood

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question. That being said, when I tried to use APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT, I noticed that it now actually scans the entire table (and therefore has a massive pricetag associated with it). Is there a way to circumvent that?